# postgreSQl 12 with GSSAPI authenticate

Tags: postgresql, authentication, kerberos, gssapi

I have been setup an authentication with Postgresql 12 using gssAPI on centos.I follow an example :https://paquier.xyz/manuals/postgresql/kerberos/ .But when i finish and run to conect with gssapi:

"psql -U "postgres/myrealm.example@MYREALM.EXAMPLE" -h myrealm.example postgres"
and i met an error :

psql: FATAL:  could not accept GSSAPI security context

FATAL:  accepting GSS security context failed

DETAIL:  Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information: Key table entry not found

I want to know  if I'm missing any configuration steps/commands or implementing something wrong.Any kind help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### Reason for problem

I ran into this same issue and spent a couple days debugging it. The issue ended up being that PostgreSQL was not configured to use the keytab that I thought I was using.

I had tried putting my keytab in the following locations:

- `/etc/krb5.keytab`
- `/usr/local/pgsql/etc/krb5.keytab`

And I tried setting the following in `/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf`:

```
krb_server_keyfile = /etc/krb5.keytab
```

This should have worked, but I think because I was using PostgreSQL through a Docker container, the config wasn't being honored properly. I also tried doing a `SHOW ALL` query which also showed the expected entry of `krb_server_keyfile = /etc/krb5.keytab`

### Solution

Finally, I set the environment variable `KRB5_KTNAME=/etc/krb5.keytab` and then my keytab got used.